# Query displays each record several times

Tags: sql, sql-server

this query display each record multiple times, i mean more than 25 times, why ?

```
SELECT        
    dbo.HrEmployee.EmplID, dbo.HrEmployee.EmplName, dbo.AtdRecord.RecDate, 
    dbo.AtdRecord.RecTime, dbo.HrDept.DeptName
FROM            
    dbo.HrDept 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.HrEmployee ON dbo.HrDept.DeptID = dbo.HrEmployee.DeptID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.AtdRecord ON dbo.HrEmployee.EmplID = dbo.AtdRecord.EmplID
```

i tried distinct but nothing worked

i am trying to post db structure

[image]

Comment: Please post db structure.

Comment: This is not helpful to answer your question either post the db structure or provide sample data and expected data

Comment: Please tell empId(AtdRecord) mapping in which column in Hrdept?

Comment: @James Post your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your understanding try this

```
SELECT        
    dbo.HrEmployee.EmplID, dbo.HrEmployee.EmplName, dbo.AtdRecord.RecDate, 
    dbo.AtdRecord.RecTime, dbo.HrDept.DeptName
FROM            
    dbo.AtdRecord 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.HrEmployee ON dbo.HrEmployee.EmplID = dbo.AtdRecord.EmplID
INNER JOIN
    dbo.HrDept ON dbo.HrDept.DeptID = dbo.HrEmployee.DeptID
```

Answer (score 1):

The effect that a join has on the number of rows returned depends on the cardinality of the relationship between the two tables that you're joining and the number of records that match your join condition. If you see the number of rows increase it's a sign that you've joined on a 1:M or M:M relationship. What you need to know to answer your question here is what is the relationship between HrDept, HrEmployee, and AtdRecord.

I would guess that HrEmployee:AtdRecord is 1:M.

Comment: HrEmployee:AtdRecord = 1:M and HrDept:HrEmployee = 1:M and

Comment: In a simpler example let's say you had 3 employees each with 5 AtdRecords. When you join on this 1:M relationship you now get 15 records even though you were selecting from Employees. Likewise you're here joining from HrDept to HrEmployee (1:M) then from HrEmployee to AtdRecord (1:M). Your result set will expand with each join as you effectively multiply the rows returned by selecting on the 1:M relationship.